# Can you review my Perl rewrite of Cucumber?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, cucumber, acceptance-testing

There is a team working on acceptance testing X11 GUI application in our company, and they created a monstrous acceptance testing framework that drives the GUI as well as running scenarios.

The framework is written using Perl 5, and scenario files look more like very complex Perl programs (thousands of lines long with procedural-programming style) than acceptance tests.

I recently learned Ruby's Cucumber, and generally have been using Ruby for quite a lot of time. But unfortunately I can't just shove Ruby to replace Perl because the people who are writing all of this don't know Ruby and it's quite certain that they wont want "this" kind of interruption.

So to bring Ruby's Cucumber a bit closer to their work, I rewrote it using Perl 5. Unfortunately I am really not a Perl programmer, and would love to get a code review and to hear suggestions from people who both know Perl and Cucumber.

Hi Perl/Cucumber StackOverflow users - please help me create this "open source" attempt to re-create Cucumber for Perl! I would love to hear your comments and will accept any acceptable help.

The minimal source code is here:

```
http://github.com/kesor/p5-cucumber
```

Thank you for your attention.

For those not familiar with cucumber - please take just one small moment to take a look at this one small little page: http://cukes.info/

Comment: It would help if you told the Perl folks what cucumber is.

Comment: Do BDD/Cucumber users really write these customized converters (p5-cucumber.pl in your example) to convert from the stylized plain-text scenarios into testing code?

Comment: I've read all the github code, it looks pretty solid.  I am intrigued by the parser.

Comment: I'm curious how you'd say this compares with Test::Cukes on cpan?
http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/Test-Cukes-0.09/lib/Test/Cukes.pm

Comment: Looks quite similar to what Test::Cukes is doing, maybe it does it differently - but in the end the result is what matters. Although T:C example couples scenarios and code together - which is not the point of that the original cucumber authors intended it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you review my Perl rewrite of
>   Cucumber?

Answer: Yes.

I've read through the github code you posted.  It looks pretty good.

I'm curious about the following snippet from Parser::Parser.yp::ERROR.   Why did you chose to use "and do {}" over "if( ){ }"?  Style? scoping? other?

```
  exists $parser->YYData->{ERRMSG}
  and do {
    print $parser->YYData->{ERRMSG};
    delete $parser->YYData->{ERRMSG};
    return;
  };
```

I haven't used cucumber and am still trying to wrap my head around the usage model.  How would someone go about verifying/running your calculator example?

If you plan to release your code to CPAN (and you should), then you'll want to bundle this git source into an installable tarball.  You'll want to include one of the module installing tools: ExtUtils::MakeMaker, Module::Build, etc.  I've recently started using [Dist::Zilla](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dist-Zilla), and am really happy with it.  It got me over the activation energy of releasing my first cpan module.

20 second tour of Dist::Zilla:

1. download and install Dist::Zilla
   and its requirements (there are
   many, as it's a developer only tool)
2. create a dist.ini file in the top
   level of your package ( 'dzil new MyPackage' )
3. run
   'dzil test', 'dzil build', and 'dzil
   release',to test, (build and test),
   (build, test and release)

See the [Dist::Zilla::Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Dist::Zilla::Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for the input, as you probably guessed it has been a while since I updated it last. About the usage of the parser, I'm pretty sure I copied it from some example - as I don't really remember why I chose to do it this way.

I remember having two branches, master with a very basic parser, and experimental with a more sophisticated one that would allow more features. Running examples is just that, "p5-cucumber example_dir" where the dir holds scenarios + test code.

Answer (score 5):

You might get good help on [Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.perl.org). That site is geared toward this sort of post, whereas Stackoverflow is more about direct and answerable questions.

Good luck, :)

Answer (score 4):

There's a rather fuller implementation of Cucumber on Perl in the form of [Test::BDD::Cucumber](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-BDD-Cucumber).

Answer (score 2):

Does [Test::A8N](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-A8N/) fit your requirement?

If not there are plenty of other [Test::](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=test%3A%3A%2A&complete=1) modules on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) which may do what you're after.

Comment: It looks nice, but it is really not cucumber. And I still use the Test:: modules in the code ... just separate the test-code from the actual story (written in plain english language). The test-code can use any framework it wants to actually "test" the conditions.

Comment: Test::A8N is based on Ward Cunningham's FIT (http://fit.c2.com/).  There are other Test::FIT* modules on CPAN of which Test::FITesque is what Test::A8N is built on top.  Cucumber seems a subset of what Test::A8N / FIT can do... so u could use it as basis for p5-cucumber.

Comment: Actually cucumber is a superset of what FIT could do, because it supports both the table notation of FIT, and the more natural - natural language notation.

Comment: I need to look at Cucumber more closely then ;-)    Check out Piers Cawley (http://www.bofh.org.uk/) because he recently mentioned that he was thinking of doing "something like cucumber" in Perl recently (http://use.perl.org/~Ovid/journal/38709)