# What are the good frameworks for unit-testing and mock objects in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking, bdd

What frameworks and tools would you recommend for unit-testing and mock objects in Perl?

I have an existing Perl application, that mainly does database access, reading and writing files. The application is basically a batch job type of application, it reads in bunch of stuff from files and database and writes a bunch of new files and some stuff to database.

The application currently does not have any unit-test, but I'd like refactor application to have good unit tests.

What frameworks and tools would you recommend for unit-testing and mocking objects? For example something similar to [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) and [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) of Java?

Also, are there any good BDD (Behaviour Driven Development) based testing frameworks for Perl?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of test frameworks, I like to use [Test::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Test-Class/lib/Test/Class.pm), which lets you set up nice unit test hierarchies in a manner similar to JUnit. The linked documentation gives a pretty good overview, though if you're not already familiar with Perl testing conventions, check out the documentation for [Test::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Test-Simple/lib/Test/Simple.pm) and [TAP](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/TAP/TAP.pm), which is the standard output format for Perl tests.

For mocking, there is [Test::Mock::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~dexter/Test-Mock-Class/lib/Test/Mock/Class.pm), which is useful for setting up mock classes for libraries outside your direct control, like CPAN modules that your application relies on.

There is also the excellent [Test::MockDBI](http://search.cpan.org/~aff/Test-MockDBI/lib/Test/MockDBI.pm) which provides special facilities for mocking your database stuff.

Comment: Test::Class is a fantastic tool for object based testing; it's lightweight and works with Test::More and all Test::Builder related unit test tools.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a little bit about BDD bit because friedo answer I think covers everthing else.

Have a quick look at this Perlmonks discussion [Behavior Driven Development: suggested tools for perl?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=750488)

I think some tools which may point you in right direction:

- [Test::Cukes](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Cukes/)
- [Test::LectroTest](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-LectroTest/)
- [Test::A8N](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-A8N/)
- [Test::FITesque](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-FITesque/)

Also see this SO question: [Can you review my Perl rewrite of Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642329/can-you-review-my-perl-rewrite-of-cucumber)

Hope some of this helps.

/I3az/

Answer (score 6):

Lately, with [MooseX::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Declare/), I've been using "real objects" as mock objects.

Say you have a database driver that does an interface like this:

```
role Database {
    requires 'connect';
    requires 'query';
};
```

Then you have code like this that uses the Database:

```
class FooPage {
    has 'database' => (
        is       => 'ro',
        does     => 'Database',
        required => 1,
    );

    method get_foo() {
        $self->database->query({ foo => 42 });
    }

    method render_page(Str $user) {
        "Hello, $user.  Here is a foo for you: ". $self->get_foo;
    }
};
```

Now you want to test this:

```
use Test::More tests => 2;
use MooseX::Declare;

my $fake_database = class with Database {
    has 'data' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'HashRef' );
    has 'connected' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Bool' );

    method connect() { $self->connected(1) }
    method query(HashRef $query) { $self->data->{$query->{foo}} }
};

my $test_database = $fake_database->name->new(
    data => {
        42 => 'OH HAI',
    },
};

my $foo_page = FooPage->new( database => $test_database );
is $foo_page->get_foo, 'OH HAI', 'got correct foo';
is $foo_page->render_page('jrockway'),
   'Hello, jrockway.  Here is a foo for you: OH HAI',
 'got rendered page';
```

Notice how you have concise syntax, but the full power of a "real"
Moose class as your mock object.  Convenient, and infinitely flexible.

(These are just examples... it could also be something much better.)

Comment: This looks damn cool, but if I was not using Moose already, I would probably skip this.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a framework, but one of the best testing books is the excellent [Perl Testing: A Developer's Notebook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596100922) which also has recommendations of test frameworks for Perl, e.g. [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::More).